# How should I connect flexible plastic duct to a metal duct?

Tags: hvac, ducts, duct-tape

I have an insulated duct like this: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Master-Flow-4-in-x-12-ft-Insulated-Flexible-Duct-R6-Silver-Jacket-F6IFD4X144/203420974

The actual tube inside is some kind of plastic. When attaching this to a metal duct, do I seal it with metal tape or duct tape? Or should I use those metal collars that can be tightened with a screw?

Comment: plastic flex duct is about the worst product you can use for ducting.  Is this for a bathroom fan?

Comment: For future reference: "metal collars that can be tightened with a screw" is commonly called a "hose clamp" or "duct clamp". In the UK, they're called "Jubilee clips". May have other names elsewhere in the world.

Answer (score 3):

Use a strap-type duct clamp.

Duct tape has no modern HVAC application that I'm aware of. Metal foil tape is a seal, not a fastener, as it tears easily.

Answer (score -2):

This is literally what duct tape was invented for.